# How to Sort the list by frequency in a descending order

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have finish my code to find top 20 words after search many times , but it is not in descending word.
I need to add the code to Sort the list by frequency in a descending order, if two words have the same  number account:

{ 'cat' => 43, 'c' => 43 }

the output should be

c

cat

My code is :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

            String delimiters = ".;_?>*/";

            String[] result = new String[20];
            List<String> listArray = new ArrayList<String>();
            Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            FileReader fileR = new FileReader("D:/test.txt");
            BufferedReader bufferedR = new BufferedReader(in);
            String line;

            while ((line = bufferedR.readLine()) != null) {
                    StringTokenizer sToken = new StringTokenizer(line, delimiters);
                    while (sToken.hasMoreTokens()) {
                        String token = sToken.nextToken().trim().toLowerCase();
                                    if (map.containsKey(token)) {
                                        int val =  map.get(token);
                                        val++;
                                        map.put(token, val);



                                    } else{
                                        map.put(token, 1);

                                    }                       
               }  
            }
            bufferedR.close();
            for(int i=0;i<result.length;i++){
                int mValu=0;
                String wKey="";
                for(Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry:map.entrySet()){
                    if(entry.getValue()>mValu){
                        mValue=entry.getValue();
                        wKey=entry.getKey();
                    }
                }
                map.remove(wKey);
                result[i]=wKey;

            }
            for (int i = 0 ; i<result.length;i++){
                System.out.println(result[i]);

        }
        }
    }
```

When i research about this subject i found this code but don't know how fit it into my code:

```
 List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> entries = new `ArrayList`<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
        public int compare(Map.Entry<String, Integer> a, Map.Entry<String, Integer> b) {
            return Integer.compare(b.getValue(), a.getValue());
        }
    });
```

Or have a better idea how to get frequency in a descending order?!

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
import java.util.Comparator.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors.*;

Map<String, Integer> map = // ...
List<String> ss = map.entrySet().stream()
                     .sorted(comparing(e -> e.getValue())
                              .reversed()
                              .thenComparing(e -> e.getKey()))
                     .map(e -> e.getKey())
                     .collect(toList());
```

Comment: I got the error after add your code, and need to create toList() method.  Could you please show which part should be add in my code. I don't know logically how it works.

Comment: I added the necessary imports

Comment: Also, can you be more specific with the ordering you expect as an output?

Comment: Let say  we have the output with top 2  as example  : "cat:37 , c:37 " i need to add additional code  to order these in this manner (descending numerical, ascending lexical). which mean the output will be :"c:37,cat:37",  first will be  "c"  and second will be "cat" as in the list and so on.

Comment: Let say the output of top 20  without sort : "apple:40","a:40","cat:37","c:37",,, output with sort: "a:40","apple:40","c:37","cat:37". -----> The output should be as this one.

Comment: I'm only have basic knowledge about java and i do my best to understand it. I don't know how your code is working. So,where should i put it, is it before close file or after close file when i added after close file i got error "e can't be resolve ". Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is sort your map. From what I understand is that you want the top 20 values, and if two values have the same token, then it should be in lexicographical order.

My solution would be to sort your map first by key (token in your case) and *then* sort by values.

This way the sorted order of the tokens will stay intact, and the map order will be in the way you want the output to be in.

**caution**
Make sure that the sorting algorithm you use is an *in place sorting algo* like Quicksort, otherwise the above solution won't work.